# An application to tikZ. A SIS epidemic model

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to graph a SIS epidemic model with Tikzpicture like the one in this page http://pythonhosted.org/epigrass/intromodels.html . My problem is I'm not able to make the arrow from the I compartment to S compartment.

Moreover I would like to add other arrows that go out of the box for considering the demography (For this I have no idea about how to proceed).

I print here my wrong code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=6cm,auto,>=latex',every node/.append style={align=center}]
    \node [int] (a)              {$S$};
    \node [int]             (c) [right of=a] {$I$};
    \path[->, auto=false] (a) edge node {$\beta I$ \\[.2em]} (c)
                          (c) edge node {$\gamma$       \\[.2em] } (e) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Provide a MWE. `int` is not defined.

Comment: This is **NOT** a MWE, one can not compile it as it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

I had to define `int` style and include `arrows` library for `latex'`.
I've also replaced `right of` with the new syntax (`positioning` library) `righ= of` (see: [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz))

For arrows going `out of the box` I've used a `coordinate` node although some other solutions are also possible.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,auto,>=latex',every node/.append style={align=center},int/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm}]
    \node [int] (S)             {$S$};
    \node [int, right=of S] (I) {$I$};
    \coordinate[right=of I] (out);
    \path[->, auto=false] (S) edge node {$\beta I$ \\[.2em]} (I)
                          (I) edge node {$\gamma$       \\[.2em] } (out) edge  [out=-120, in=-60] node[below] {$\delta$} (S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

Torbjørn T. proposed some more improvements to your code:

Replacing syntax `node {$\beta I$ \\[.2em]}` with simply `node[above] {$\beta I$}` which is the `TiKZ` way for placing an edge label above the arrow. In this case, as you already included `auto` option, there's no need for `[above]` because edge labels are automatically placed following arrow direction. You stopped this automatism with `auto=false`.

Using new `arrows.meta` library instead of deprecated (although still supported) `arrows`. As an example, `latex'` style has been replaced by `Latex`

The new code is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, auto,
    >=Latex, 
    every node/.append style={align=center},
    int/.style={draw, minimum size=1cm}]

   \node [int] (S)             {$S$};
   \node [int, right=of S] (I) {$I$};
   \coordinate[right=of I] (out);
   \path[->] (S) edge node {$\beta I$} (I)
             (I) edge node {$\gamma$} (out) 
                 edge[out=-120, in=-60] node {$\delta$} (S);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better with e.g. `node [above] {$\beta I$}` instead of adding a linebreak? (I know it came from the OPs code.) And not that I consider it a big deal, but the manual for v3 states that the `arrows` library is considered deprecated in favor of `arrows.meta`, as you probably know.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right. I've not seen it. I've included your suggestions. Thank you for pointing them.